Summing rows in a Pandas DataFrame where the number of rows summed is based on columns values in a different DataFrame
I have two Dataframes.
Dataframe1(df1):
Column B is initially empty and needs to be populated as below.
| A( in days) | B (sum) |
| ----------- | ------- |
| 7           |         |
| 14          |         |
| 18          |         |
| 25          |         |

df1 has two  columns:
Column A in days and another column B that is blank and needs to be filled with sum of rows from dataframe 2,the number of rows to be summed is  based on how days translates to week in column B.
Dateframe 2 (df2):
| week | C(weekly) |
| ---- | --------- |
| WK1  | 10        |
| WK2  | 5         |
| WK3  | 7         |
| WK4  | 4         |
| WK5  | 8         |

Dataframe 2 has two columns:
This dataframe has Week numbers and weekly which is sum of weekly units.
I want to fill the values in column A of dataframe 1 based on column d in Dataframe 2 like below:
For first row when A=7 days then just use WK1 values (As 7 days is 1 week so just WK1 of C from DF2) so B=10
For second row when A=14 days (2 weeks), I need WK1 and WK2 sum for C from DF2) so B=10+5=15
For third row, when A=18,I need the sum of WK1 and WK2 and 5/7(WK3) of C from DF2) so B=10+5+(4/7)*7=19
For fourth row, when A=25, I need the sum of WK1+Wk2+wk3+(4/7)*4,so B=24.28 (3 weeks plus fraction -21day + 4/7th of week4 value)
df1 (Completed):
| A( in days) | B(sum) | Methodology     |
| ----------- | ------- | --------------- |
| 7           | 10      | 10              |
| 14          | 15      | 10+5            |
| 18          | 19      | 10+5+(4/7)*7    |
| 25          | 24.28   | 10+5+7+(4/7)*4  |

I am new to python and do now know how to proceed. Please help

Are you sure of the last computation? Shouldn't it be 10+5+(4/7*7)+4?

Actually I got it

the number of weeks is equal to the number of rows (with potentially a few days missing)
IIUC, you can use a mod operation to correct the cumsum:
r = df1['A'].mod(7).to_numpy()
c = df2['C'].head(len(df1))
df1['B'] = c.cumsum().sub((7-r)/7*c.where(r>0), fill_value=0).to_numpy()

Output:
    A          B
0   7  10.000000
1  14  15.000000
2  18  19.000000
3  25  24.285714

the number of weeks is arbitrary
Then we need to use a custom function
def cust_sum(n, ref):
    d, r = divmod(n, 7)
    return ref.head(d).sum() + (ref.iat[d]*r/7 if r else 0)

df1['B'] = df1['A'].apply(cust_sum, ref=df2['C'])

Example:
    A          B
0   7  10.000000
1  14  15.000000
2  18  19.000000
3  29  27.142857


Thanks for your help. This works. I however wanted to use the dataframes with unequal lengths (df2>df1). so say the in df1 the last row is 36 days then I wanted the B to read 10+5+7+4+(1/7)*8=27.14. Where  8 is week 5 value from df2.  When I use the above logic and make the last row in df1 36 then it gives me 'Array conditional must be same shape as self'. How can this be incorporated? thanks

@One_more_time I see, but are you sure you meant 36 and not 29? For 36 this would be 5 weeks + 1 day, but df2 doesn't have data for the 6th week. I would have considered 10+5+7+4+8+(x/7*1) where x is the value of W6.

I added an approach assuming you meant 29

Yes you interpreted it correctly. This works. Thank you so much for your help. Greatly appreciated.    The only question I had is about the n in the custom function. Is that the value in the nth row of the df1['A']?

Yes, you got it ;)

I was using this and found that I need to do this same logic but for a value match between combination of two additional categorical columns both present in df1 and df2 - so like if df1 will have column X and column Y with values say 'a' and 'b' and df2 also has the columns X and Y - then this logic need to work only for similar combination of columns (so with 'a' for column X and 'b' for column Y in DF2)-- How do that make that work?     do  I need to create an fresh post for this? I could do that if needed. I am new to all this so could not anticipate this need. Please advise.

@One_more_time please understand that the question shouldn't keep changing (see chameleon questions) and what should I go when someone answers my question. In this case it's quite simple: df1['out1'] = df1['X'].apply(cust_sum, ref=df2['X']) and df1['out2'] = df1['Y'].apply(cust_sum, ref=df2['Y']).

Sorry If I was not clear but I need to use both column X and Y together and not separately . I tried doing the following: df1a= df1.groupby(['X','Y']).agg({'A':mean}) and df2a=df2.groupby(['X','Y']).agg({'C':mean}).  As these are unique values I get the same values as original when I take the mean. Then used these per what you had shown earlier: df1a['B'] = df1a['A'].apply(cust_sum, ref=df2a['C']). Then I get an error "cannot do positional indexing on MultiIndex with these indexers [1.0] of type float. Please help.

thanks for all the help.  You have been fantastic. I have accepted the answer but I cannot  vote on it as I do not have 15 reputation to cast a vote. I will go ahead a create a new post with the two additional columns also being part of the both dataframes.

FYI - I  have asked the above question with the requirement for value match between combination of two additional categorical columns in a new post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78714936/cumulative-sum-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-multiple-column-value-matches-betwee

@One_more_time thanks, it's much more explicit this way, THB I would not have guesses what you wanted without the full question. I answered there.
