Cumulative sum in Pandas DataFrame based on multiple column value matches between two dataframes
I have two Dataframes.
Dataframe1(df1): has 4 columns as shown below.



X
Y
A( in days)
B(sum)




a
aa
7



a
bb
9



b
aa
36



c
dd
29




Column X and Column Y are strings and Column A in days and another column B that is blank and needs to be filled with sum of rows from dataframe 2,the number of rows to be summed is based on how days translates to week in column B.
Dateframe 2 (df2):



X
Y
Week
C(weekly)




a
aa
WK1
10


a
aa
WK2
23


a
aa
WK3
21


a
aa
WK4
2


a
aa
Wk5
5








a
bb
WK1
10


a
bb
WK2
7


a
bb
WK3
14








b
aa
WK1
10


b
aa
WK2
5


b
aa
WK3
4


b
aa
WK4
8


b
aa
Wk5
7


b
aa
Wk6
18


b
aa
Wk7
3


b
aa
WK8
7








c
dd
WK1
10


c
dd
WK2
5


c
dd
WK3
7


c
dd
WK4
14


c
dd
WK5
7


c
dd
WK4
21



Dataframe 2 also has four columns. Column X and Column Y are string and this dataframe has Week numbers and weekly which is sum of weekly units.
I want to fill the values in column B of df1 based on column C in df2 like below:
For first row in df1  when X=a and Y =aa and A=7 days then from df2  find corresponding matching values of a and aa in columns X and Y and then use just WK1 values (As 7 days is 1 week so just WK1 of C from df2) so B=10 in df1
For second row in df1  when X=a and Y =bb and A=9 days then from df2  find corresponding matching values of a and bb in columns X and Y and then use WK1 + (2/7)WK2  (As 7 days is 1 week plus 2 additional days i.e. a fraction (2/7th) of week 2  value so  10+7(2/7) giving B=12
For third  row in df1  when X=b and Y =aa and A=36 days then from df2  find corresponding matching values of b and aa in columns X and Y and then use WK1+WK2+WK3+WK4+WK5+(1/7)WK6  (As 36 days is 5 weeks plus 1 additional day i.e. a fraction (1/7th) of week 6  value so  10+5+4+8+7+18(1/7) giving B=36.5
and so on.
df1 (Completed):



X
Y
A( in days)
B(sum)
Methodology




a
aa
7
10
a-aa-WK1-10


a
bb
9
10+7*(2/7)=12
a-bb- Wk1+(2/7)*WK2


b
aa
36
10+5+4+8+7+18*(1/7)=36.5
b-aa-WK1+WK2+WK3+WK4+WK5+(1/7)*WK6


c
dd
29
10+5+7+14+(1/7)*7=37
c-dd-WK1+WK2+Wk3+(1/7)*WK4



PS: I had an earlier post on this where I asked this question without the requirements for two columns X and Y in df1 to match with those in df2 --it was only after working on this for a little bit did i realize that I will need to do this with a match with the columns X and Y so reposting the additional requirement. I did gain very valuable insights from my previous post but I have to get the above solved to complete my task.
So please don't close this as a duplicate.
I am a newbie to python and programming so am still learning all the various concepts - please help.
Based on answer I got from my previous post:
Summing rows in a Pandas DataFrame where the number of rows summed is based on columns values in a different DataFrame
I tried doing the following:
df1a= df1.groupby(['X','Y']).agg({'A':mean})
and df2a=df2.groupby(['X','Y']).agg({'C':mean}).
As these are unique values I get the same values as original when I take the mean.
Then used the function from earlier post: df1a['B'] = df1a['A'].apply(cust_sum, ref=df2a['C']).
But I get an error "cannot do positional indexing on MultiIndex with these indexers [1.0] of type float"

You could adapt my previous approach to use it per group with groupby.apply:
def cust_sum(n, ref):
    d, r = divmod(n, 7)
    return ref.head(d).sum() + (ref.iat[d]*r/7 if r else 0)

g2 = df2.groupby(['X', 'Y'])['C']

df1['B'] = (df1
  .groupby(['X', 'Y'], group_keys=False)
  .apply(lambda x: x['A'].apply(cust_sum, ref=g2.get_group(x.name)),
         include_groups=False)
)

Output:
   X   Y   A          B
0  a  aa   7  10.000000
1  a  bb   9  12.000000
2  b  aa  36  36.571429
3  c  dd  29  37.000000


This works - thank you so much for you help. I had to drop the 'include_groups=False' in the last part to make it work so the last part that I have is.  df1['B'] = (df1
.groupby(['X', 'Y'], group_keys=False)
.apply(lambda x: x['A'].apply(cust_sum, ref=g2.get_group(x.name)))
)

@One_more_time this is an option for the latest pandas versions, if you have an older pandas you should indeed remove it.

Code
# Reset index & merge df1 and df2
tmp = df1.reset_index().merge(df2, how='left')

# Calculate the number of complete weeks and remaining days
week, days = tmp['A( in days)'] // 7, tmp['A( in days)'] % 7

# Extract the numerical part of the 'Week' column and convert it to an integer
s = tmp['Week'].str.extract(r'(\d+)')[0].astype('int')

# Define conditions for masking
cond1 = s <= week
cond2 = s == week + 1

# Calculate the new 'C(weekly)' values based on conditions
tmp2 = (
    tmp['C(weekly)']
    .mask(cond2, tmp['C(weekly)'] * days / 7)
    .where(cond1 | cond2)
    .groupby(tmp['index'])
    .sum()
)

# Drop the 'B(sum)' column and join tmp2 and rename to 'B(sum)'
out = df1.drop('B(sum)', axis=1).join(tmp2.rename('B(sum)'))

out
   X   Y  A( in days)     B(sum)
0  a  aa            7  10.000000
1  a  bb            9  12.000000
2  b  aa           36  36.571429
3  c  dd           29  37.000000

Example Code
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'X': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 'Y': ['aa', 'bb', 'aa', 'dd'], 'A( in days)': [7, 9, 36, 29], 'B(sum)': [float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan')]}
data2 = {'X': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'], 'Y': ['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'bb', 'bb', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'dd', 'dd', 'dd', 'dd', 'dd', 'dd'], 'Week': ['WK1', 'WK2', 'WK3', 'WK4', 'Wk5', 'WK1', 'WK2', 'WK3', 'WK1', 'WK2', 'WK3', 'WK4', 'Wk5', 'Wk6', 'Wk7', 'WK8', 'WK1', 'WK2', 'WK3', 'WK4', 'WK5', 'WK6'], 'C(weekly)': [10, 23, 21, 2, 5, 10, 7, 14, 10, 5, 4, 8, 7, 18, 3, 7, 10, 5, 7, 14, 7, 21]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)


This works - thanks for your help. The actual data I got has week in  datetime format 'YYYY-MM-DD' starting saturday every week. I had to map it to Week 1, Week 2 etc. Is there a way to make your code work with the datatime Week? Please ignore if that is considered a scope creep from my original question
